# Searching in ShellWindows under UAC

Tags: javascript, uac, jscript, wsh, hta

I have a JScript application which runs a HTA window to communicate with user. It starts HTA app with specific ID, then searches through shellWindows collection for the window with this ID and gets control on it.
It works fine in most cases, but on Windows 7 with UAC on the script need to elevate its rights. When it does so, the createHTAWindow function doesn't work more 'cause it can't find the HTA window in shellWindows collection. If the script doesn't try to elevate its rights, then HTA part works fine.
Here are the example of the code to reproduce the problem. It works on Windows 7 with UAC off or with both UAC on and Elevate variable in False state. But if the UAC is on and Elevate == True then it doesn't :/

```
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var Elevate = true;

function main(){
    var oXMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");    
    innerhtml =
        "<html> " +
        "<head> " +
        "<title>Test HTA window</title> " +
        "<HTA:APPLICATION " +
        "APPLICATIONNAME='test' " +
        "VERSION='1.0' " +
        "BORDER='none' " +
        "CAPTION='yes' " +
        "INNERBORDER='no' " +
        "CONTEXTMENU='no' " +
        "SCROLL='no' " +
        "MAXIMIZEBUTTON='no' " +
        "MINIMIZEBUTTON='no' " +
        "SELECTION='no' " +
        "/> " +
        "<STYLE> " +
        "body{ " +
        "font-family:Verdana; " +
        "font-size:11px; " +
        "} " +
        "</STYLE> " +
        "</head> " +
        "<script language='javascript'> " +
        "function window.onload(){ " +
        "self.focus(); " +
        "self.resizeTo(300,80); " +
        "} " +
        "</script> " +
        "<body scroll=no bgcolor='D4D0C8' style='border:0;'> " +
        "<center> Test HTA window " +
        "<br><br> " +
        " It will be closed in 10 sec " +
        "</center> " +
        "</body> " +
        "</html> ";
    width = 300; height = 80;
    var window = createHTAWindow(innerhtml,0,0,width,height);
    window.moveTo((window.screen.width-width)/2,(window.screen.height-height)/2);
    WScript.Sleep(10000);
    window.close();
}
// function createHTAWindow by JSman
function createHTAWindow(content, x, y, width, height)
{
var HTASettings = "", e, window, Host = this; 
    width = Number(width) || 400;
    height = Number(height) || 300;
    try {
        HTASettings = content.match(/<hta[^>]+>/gim)[0].replace(/\r?\n/g, " ").replace(/"/g,"'");
    } catch(e) {
    }

    var ID = "u"+Math.floor(Math.random()*10000000)
    var CodeForLinking = "\"<title> </title><script>moveTo(-300,-300); resizeTo(0,0)</script>" + 
        HTASettings + 
        "<object id=" + ID + 
        " classid='clsid:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2'><param name=RegisterAsBrowser value=1></object>\"";
    var ShellWindows = ( new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application") ).Windows();
    var NumberOfWindows = ShellWindows.Count;

    WshShell.Run("mshta.exe about:"+CodeForLinking);

// for debug purpose
WScript.Sleep(1000);
var s="ID: " + ID + "\n";
for (var i=ShellWindows.Count; --i>=0;){
    s = s + i + ": " + ShellWindows.Item(i).id + "\n";
}
WScript.Echo(s);

    outer: for (var t=0; t<500; t++)    
    inner:  for (var i=ShellWindows.Count; --i>=0;){
        try{
            if( ShellWindows.Item(i).id == ID ){
                window = ShellWindows.Item(i).parent.parentWindow;
                break outer;
            }
        } catch(e) {
            WScript.Echo(e.message);
            return false;
        }
        WScript.Sleep(10);
    }

    if (!window) {
        WshShell.Popup("Error", 0, "Error", 0+48);
        WScript.Quit();
        return false;
    }

    try {
        window.document.open(); window.Host = Host; 
        window.document.write([content||"", "<script language='JScript'>eval;resizeTo(",width,",", height,"); moveTo(", Number(x) ||  (window.screen.width - width) / 2,",", Number(y) || (window.screen.height - height) / 2, ");</script>"].join(""));
        window.document.close();
    } catch (e) {
    }
    return window;
}

if ( Elevate && WScript.Arguments.Count() == 0 ) {
    var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
    oShell.ShellExecute("wscript.exe", "\"" + WScript.ScriptFullName + "\"" + " /isElevated", WScript.ScriptFullName.slice(0,-WScript.ScriptName.length-1), "runas", 1);
    WScript.Quit();
}

main();
```

Could you explain please why this happens and suggest something to solve this problem?

Comment: For some reason I can "catch" Resource Manager windows only, when using `Windows()`. You could try `WbemScripting.SWbemLocator` instead of `Shell.Application`. There's an example how to get windows via WMI in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14042537/1169519

Comment: @Teemu, do you mean you can catch Resource Manager windows only in both UAC on and off modes? I read those question but there is described only the way how to terminate the `mshta.exe` process but not how to get the `window` object.

Comment: I haven't even tried UAC on... Anyway, please check the code in that question again, all mshta.exe windows are read into the `Enumerator` named `htas` in the code.

Comment: @Teemu, `htas Enumerator` contains `mshta.exe` processes, not windows. If you know how to get the window object with process object, please tell me.

Comment: Ähh... My bad, `window` and `process` really are not equal...