# How to close a HTA window from another HTA?

Tags: jscript, hta, activexobject

I've tried to implement my own modal dialogs ([Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11727815/1169519)). I open a new window using `WScript.Shell`:

```
dlg = shell.Run(dlgPath, 1, true);
```

The line above creates a "semi-modal" HTA window. The script execution is stopped at this line, but the main window is still responsive. This issue is tackled within `onfocusin` eventhandler, which returns focus back to the new HTA window using `shell.AppActivate()`. This prevents even "Close Window" button to close the main window. However, in Windows7 there's a back gate to close the main window, the icon in Windows Task Bar.

If the main window is closed, a decent modal dialog should be closed as well. In this case it is not closed, since the opened HTA window is not a real child window of the main.

I can close this dialog emulator within main window's `onbeforeunload` handler function below.

```
beforeTopClose = function () {
    var wmiLocator = new ActiveXObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator'),
        wmiService = wmiLocator.ConnectServer('.', 'root\\CIMV2'),
        htas = new Enumerator(wmiService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where name = 'mshta.exe'"));
    while (!htas.atEnd()) {
        if (htas.item().CommandLine.indexOf('_tools\\dlgbase') > -1) {
            htas.item().Terminate(0);
        }
        htas.moveNext();
    }
    return;
}
```

Now everything looks good, there are no windows of my app left on the screen. However, when I open Windows Task Manager Processes -tab, I can see the process of the *main window* still running.

Why the main window is still running? Is it waiting for the end of the `shell`-process? What should I do in `onbeforeunload` handler to get the main window closed totally? If I need a different approach to this, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized, that I can terminate the main window as well in `beforeTopClose()`. Fixed code below.

```js
beforeTopClose = function () {
    var thisHta = {},
        thisHtaPath = lib.shell.currentDirectory + '\\index.hta', // Path to current HTA
        htas = new Enumerator(lib.wmiService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where name = 'mshta.exe'"));
    while (!htas.atEnd()) {
        if (htas.item().CommandLine.indexOf('_tools\\dlgbase') > -1) {
            htas.item().Terminate();
        }
        if (htas.item().CommandLine.indexOf(thisHtaPath) > -1) {
            thisHta = htas.item();
        }
        htas.moveNext();
    }
    thisHta.Terminate();
    return;
}
```