# Use WScript.Sleep() or replacement in mshta.exe one-liner

Tags: sleep, jscript, wsh, hta

I want to use `WScript.Sleep()` function with a `mshta.exe` one-liner from a batch (I don't want to write temporary files) but I receive a `WScript undefined` error.

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38880978/6456701):

> WScript is an object provided by the W|CScript.exe hosts; IExplorer or
>   MSHTA don't provide it (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8915571/603855)).

In [Sleep routine for HTA scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16865430/6456701):

- [Stephen Quan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28458312/6456701)
  uses `window.setTimeOut` and `window.ResizeTo` which just threw
  errors (but maybe there is a way to do it that I don't find).
- [uk2015's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30134441/6456701) is VBScript.
- [iRon's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16865431/6456701): error in
  character 5 ';' expected; also, the `select` has single quotes (in
  `mshta`, the parameter is double-quoted and you can use single quotes
  inside, but this is third level of *quotification*, so to speak. Furthermore, you need admin rights.
- [TorATB's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26139244/6456701): uses a ping! Same problem with quotes too.

I don't know how to make a single answer of these work or if possible.

Inside a `.js` run by c/wscript it works perfectly. Is there a replacement or a way to reference this function for `mshta.exe`?

Example:

Save the following code as `.js` and run it.

```
new ActiveXObject('Internet.HHCtrl').TextPopup('Warning message', 'Tahoma, 16, , BOLD', 8, 4, 0x0000FF, 0x00FFFF );WScript.Sleep(5000);
```

But, as I said, I want to run it from a batch without any temporary `.js` (or `.vbs`). Try running this code from a Command Prompt:

```
mshta "javascript:new ActiveXObject('Internet.HHCtrl').TextPopup('Warning message', 'Tahoma, 16, , BOLD', 8, 4, 0x0000FF, 0x00FFFF );close()"
```

The text popup opens and closes immediately but you can manage to see it sometimes. How do you manage to hold the text during a given amount of time when you run this code using `mshta`?

Comment: I found that question, but refers to `.hta` files and I don't see how the answers (that create _sleep_ functions) can be adapted to a `mshta "javascript: ...;close()"` commands (one of them is `.vbs` actually). I add about this in the question.

Comment: `mshta vbscript:Close(Execute("CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"").Run ""ping.exe 100.64.1.1 -n 1 -w 2000"",0,True"))` Try this, but Windows Defender blocks it.

Comment: It uses the ping method, but 100.64.1.1 is in a reserved space that should never actually ping (unlike 1.1.1.1 which was common before). The `-w` parameter is in milliseconds.

Comment: @langstrom Good. But yours is _vbscript_. Anyway, wouldn't that run `ping` asynchronously and the code will resume immediately? And I have concerns, in general, with the use of pinging to create a delay, because there are several scenarios where it will fail and quickly return from the pings: if you don't have a network card (rare nowadays, I know) or if it's disabled for whatever reason at the time of the ping (not so unlikely) or even if you were connected to a WiFi but it's reconnecting then (definitely possible). I think using `0.0.0.0` or `127.0.0.1` is more secure but even then...

Comment: @cdlvcdlv Can you share your batch code ?

Comment: @Hackoo OK. It's a very simple command indeed. I add it to the question. I didn't until now because tried to make the question as general an useful as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example showing you how to make a sleep with a HTA

```
<html>
<head>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
APPLICATIONNAME="Volume + - ON/OFF" 
BORDER="THIN" 
BORDERSTYLE="NORMAL" 
ICON="SndVol.exe" 
INNERBORDER="NO" 
MAXIMIZEBUTTON="NO" 
MINIMIZEBUTTON="NO" 
SCROLL="NO" 
SELECTION="NO" 
SINGLEINSTANCE="YES"/>
<title>Volume + - ON/OFF </title>
<script language="vbscript">
'************************************************************************************
Sub window_onload()
    CenterWindow 250,150
End Sub
'************************************************************************************
Sub Sleep(MSecs)' Function to pause because wscript.sleep does not work with HTA 
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim tempFolder : Set tempFolder = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2)
    Dim tempName : tempName = "Sleeper.vbs"
    If Not Fso.FileExists(tempFolder&"\"&tempName) Then
        Set objOutputFile = fso.CreateTextFile(tempFolder&"\"&tempName, True)
        objOutputFile.Write "wscript.sleep WScript.Arguments(0)"
        objOutputFile.Close
    End If
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run tempFolder&"\"&tempName &" "& MSecs,1,True
End Sub
'************************************************************************************
Sub Volume(Param)
    set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
    Select Case Param 
    Case "MAX"
        oShell.run "%SystemRoot%\System32\SndVol.exe" 'Runs The Master Volume App.
        Sleep 2000 'Waits For The Program To Open
        oShell.SendKeys("{HOME}")' volume maximum 100%
        Sleep 100
        oShell.SendKeys"%{F4}"  ' ALT + F4
    Case "MIN"
        oShell.run "%SystemRoot%\System32\SndVol.exe" 'Runs The Master Volume App.
        Sleep 2000 'Waits For The Program To Open
        oShell.SendKeys("{END}") 'volume minimum 0% 
        Sleep 1000
        oShell.SendKeys"%{F4}"  ' ALT + F4
    Case "UP"
        oShell.run "%SystemRoot%\System32\SndVol.exe" 'Runs The Master Volume App.
        Sleep 2000 'Waits For The Program To Open
        oShell.SendKeys("{PGUP}") 'volume +20%
        Sleep 1000
        oShell.SendKeys"%{F4}"  ' ALT + F4
    Case "DOWN"
        oShell.run "%SystemRoot%\System32\SndVol.exe" 'Runs The Master Volume App.
        Sleep 2000 'Waits For The Program To Open
        oShell.SendKeys("{PGDN}") 'Turns Up The Volume 20, If It Is Muted Then It Will Unmute It
        Sleep 1000
        oShell.SendKeys"%{F4}"  ' ALT + F4
    Case "MUTE"
        oShell.run "%SystemRoot%\System32\SndVol.exe" 'Runs The Master Volume App.
        Sleep 1000 'Waits For The Program To Open
        oShell.SendKeys(" " & chr(173)) 'permet de couper/remettre le son (bascule)
        Sleep 1000
        oShell.SendKeys"%{F4}"  ' ALT + F4
    End select
End Sub
'*************************************************************************************
Sub CenterWindow(x,y)
    Dim iLeft,itop
    window.resizeTo x,y
    iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2
    itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2
    window.moveTo ileft,itop
End Sub
'************************************************************************************
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<BUTTON style="background: Red; color: white;" onClick="Call Volume('MAX')" style="WIDTH: 85px; HEIGHT: 30px">Volume MAX</BUTTON>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<BUTTON style="background: Blue; color: white;" onClick="Call Volume('MIN')" style="WIDTH: 85px; HEIGHT: 30px">Volume MIN</BUTTON>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<BUTTON style="background: Green; color: white;" onClick="Call Volume('UP')" style="WIDTH: 85px; HEIGHT: 30px">Volume +20%</BUTTON>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<BUTTON style="background: Orange; color: white;" onClick="Call Volume('DOWN')" style="WIDTH: 85px; HEIGHT: 30px">Volume -20%</BUTTON>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<BUTTON style="background: DarkOrange; color: white;" onClick="Call Volume('MUTE')" style="WIDTH: 85px; HEIGHT: 30px">ON/OFF</BUTTON>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And this code can be run from a mshta one-liner? The function is actually a temporary `.vbs` file you run every time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit question, you can do something like this with a batch file :

```dos
@echo off
Title Execute a .JS and .VBS file in a batch script
echo Hello World !
Set "JS_Warning=%Temp%\Warning.js"
Set "VBS_Msg=%Temp%\Msg.vbs"
REM Create a .js temporary file
echo new ActiveXObject('Internet.HHCtrl'^).TextPopup('Warning message', 'Tahoma, 16, , BOLD', 8, 4, 0x0000FF, 0x00FFFF ^);WScript.Sleep(5000^);>"%JS_Warning%"
REM Create a .vbs temporary file
echo CreateObject("Internet.HHCtrl"^).TextPopup "Hello !" ^& vbCrLf ^& "How are you ?", "Verdana,8", 6, 6, 6, 6 : WScript.Sleep 5000>"%VBS_Msg%"
REM We execute the .js file
Wscript "%JS_Warning%"
REM We execute the .vbs file
Wscript "%VBS_Msg%"
```

Comment: Please read my question: "I don't want to write temporary files", " Is there a replacement or a way to reference this function for mshta.exe?". It's clear I'm aware of these possibilities. I know you can even create a hybrid script, but it's not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Sleep(lngDelay)
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "Timeout /T " & lngDelay & " /nobreak", 0, True
End Sub

Sleep 1
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Try WMI event notification query.
The following query example shows you how to generate events every second forever.

```
SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WHERE TargetInstance ISA "Win32_LocalTime"
```

You could use `SWbemServices.ExecNotificationQuery` method to subscribe to events.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sleep</title>
  <HTA:APPLICATION>
</head>
<body>
<script language="javascript">
window.resizeTo(640, 480);

var CIMv2 = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\\\.\\root\\CIMv2")

function sleep(count) {
    var event_gen = CIMv2.ExecNotificationQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WHERE TargetInstance ISA \"Win32_LocalTime\"")
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        event_gen.NextEvent();
    }
}

for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    sleep(3)
    alert("3 seconds passed")
}

document.write("<h1>Goodbye</h1>");
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't see clear what should be the _mshta_ one-liner, as stated in the question.