# mshta.exe process keeps running after closing HTA

Tags: pdf, iframe, process, hta

I'm developing a HTA app, which shows pdf files in an `iframe` by dynamically setting `src` of the `iframe`.

HTML:

```
<iframe id="preview" src="" application="yes"></iframe>
```

The relevant script:

```
var path = 'some_path/file_name.pdf';
document.getElementById('preview').src = path;
```

This works well, but when I close the app, I can still see mshta.exe running in Task Manager's Processes tab. If any pdf is never loaded to `iframe`, the mshta.exe process is terminated properly. There's also no troubles if a .htm file is loaded instead of a .pdf. The problem occurs only, if any of the loaded pdfs is a 3D pdf, which is run by A3DUtility.exe.

Loading a .htm file to `iframe` in onbeforeunload handler doesn't fix the problem. The only working solution I've found, is to kill A3DUtility.exe process via WMI (the script below). However, it's a bit brutal way to close a program, since I can't be sure if there's other windows running an embedded A3DUtility.exe too.

```
beforeTopClose = function () {
    var pdf,
        pdfs = new Enumerator(lib.wmiService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where name = 'A3DUtility.exe'"));
    while (!pdfs.atEnd()) {
        if (pdfs.item().CommandLine.indexOf('-Embedding') > -1) {
            pdf = pdfs.item();
        }
        pdfs.moveNext();
    }
    if (pdf) {
        pdf.Terminate();
    }
    return;
}
```

Is there anything I can do to close a 3D pdf within `iframe` properly before closing the app?

---

**Edit**

This appeared to has something to do with the previous version of A3DUtility.exe itself. When I updated Adobe Reader (from 10 to 11), the problem is not occuring anymore.

Comment: It stills happens with me. It keeps running until you forcefully close it or logout the system. (Windows 10, not using iframe)

Comment: @FernandoVieira Have you tried the DC version of Adobe Reader? It looks like it is closed properly when the window is closed, with a delay of a couple of seconds, though.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant. My issue doesn't have to do with Adobe Reader. I'm not using it. My HTA is a pretty standard HTML page with ajax calls to a legacy ASP page to show some content. When it's finished, I call "window.close()" which closes the window fine, but the mshta.exe process still goes on...

Comment: @FernandoVieira Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14042537/1169519), there's a code snippet (in the question) you can use to close a hta window on beforeclose event. If that doesn't help, maybe you should ask a question about your issue.

Comment: Great tip @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant It seems to be the best solution so far!

Comment: @FernandoVieira Notice, that it's a bit hackish to terminate a process. If your code contains ActiveX commands like `WScript.Shell.Run(path, 1, true);`, changing the `true` argument to `false` might help. If the argument is `true`, HTA waits for the termination of the executed program. If that is not specifically needed, then rather pass `false` to immediately continue the execution of the script in the HTA app.